# Getting returned wrong values, but reading in fine in system? Java

Tags: java

I am trying to read in this input:

```
processcount 2     # Read 2 processes
runfor 15          # Run for 15 time units
use rr             # Can be fcfs, sjf, or rr
quantum 2          # Time quantum – only if using rr
process name P1 arrival 3 burst 5
process name P2 arrival 0 burst 9
end
```

My job is to only parse in the values and not the words, and to keep out the comments (#).

Here is the main file:

```
public class main {

static String[] token = new String[10];
static List<Schedule> p;

public static void schedule()
{
    for(Schedule c: p)
    {
         System.out.println("ProcessInfo: " + c.getProcess().processName);
            System.out.println("count: " + c.getProcessCount());
             System.out.println("quant: " + c.getQuantum());
              System.out.println("runtime: " + c.getRunTime());
               System.out.println("Type: " + c.getType());
    }
  }


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      // sc = new Scanner(new File("processes.in"));
    p = new ArrayList<>();

    while(sc.hasNextLine() && !sc.equals("end"))
    {

        token = sc.nextLine().replace(" ","-").replace("#", "-").split("-");

        System.out.println(token[0].toString());


        if(!token[0].startsWith("#") || !sc.nextLine().startsWith("end"))
        {
            Schedule s = new Schedule();
            int pCount=0, runfor=0, quantum=0, arrival=0, burst=0;
            String type = null, pName = null;

            if(token[0].startsWith("processcount"))
            {
                 s.setProcessCount(Integer.parseInt(token[1]));
                System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(token[1] +""));
            }


            else if(token[0].startsWith("runfor"))
            {
                  s.setRunTime(Integer.valueOf(token[1].toString()));
                 System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(token[1]) +"");
            }

            else if(token[0].startsWith("use"))
            {
                s.setType(token[1].toString());
                System.out.println(token[1] +"");
            }

            else if(token[0].startsWith("quantum"))
            {
                s.setQuantum(Integer.valueOf(token[1].toString()));
                System.out.println(token[1] + "");
            }

            else if(token[0].startsWith("process"))
            {
                Processes pl = new Processes();
                pl.setProcessName(token[2]);
                System.out.println(token[2]+ "");

                pl.setArrivalTime(Integer.valueOf(token[4].toString()));
                System.out.println(""+ Integer.valueOf(token[4]));

                pl.setBurstTime(Integer.valueOf(token[6].toString()));
                System.out.println("" + token[6]);

                s.setProcess(pl);
                // add info
                p.add(s);

            }

            else if(token[0].startsWith("end"))
            {
                schedule();
            }

        }

    }

}

}
```

Here is the Schedule:

```
public class Schedule { 

int processCount;
int runTime;
String type;
int quantum;
Processes process;


public  int getProcessCount() {
    return processCount;
}

public  void setProcessCount(int processCount) {
    this.processCount = processCount;
}

public int getRunTime() {
    return runTime;
}

public  void setRunTime(int runTime) {
    this.runTime = runTime;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public int getQuantum() {
    return quantum;
}

public void setQuantum(int quantum) {
    this.quantum = quantum;
}

public Processes getProcess() {
    return process;
}

public void setProcess(Processes p) {
    process = p;
}
}
```

Here is the Process:

```
public class Processes {

String processName;
int arrivalTime;
int burstTime;

public String getProcessName() {
    return processName;
}

public void setProcessName(String processName) {
    this.processName = processName;
}
public int getArrivalTime() {
    return arrivalTime;
}

public void setArrivalTime(int arrivalTime) {
   this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
}

public int getBurstTime() {
    return burstTime;
}

public void setBurstTime(int burstTime) {
    this.burstTime = burstTime;
}
}
```

Here is the output I am getting with my code:

```
ProcessInfo: P1
count: 0
quant: 0
runtime: 0
Type: null
ProcessInfo: P2
count: 0
quant: 0
runtime: 0
Type: null
```

why am I getting returned wrong results?

Comment: Just from looking at your code: (1) Your comparison `sc.equals("end")` will never be true - one is a `Scanner`, the other a `String`. I think you mean `sc.next().equals("end")`. Learn to debug your code! (2) You instantiate several variables, but never assign values to them. (3) Your choice of variable names (`c`, `p`, etc.) does not make for very readable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's couple of issue here. You create a new schedule at each iteration of your while loop; you don't get all the relevant values of your current line before the new iteration plus you have couple of useless variables right after you create a new Schedule() which override the previously collected values.
Also, you use toString on a String element of your array which is meaningless. Personnaly I don't try not to use filters and you don't really need any for this. Always try to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)(Keep It Simple Stupid)

Here's how I'll go about it without using filters.

```
public static void main (String args [])
{
     // Will help us identify the key words
     String current_token;

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

     String input = sc.nextLine();
     //Remove spaces at the beginning and end of the string
     input = input.trim();

     Schedule s = new Schedule();

     // New source for the scanner
     sc =new Scanner(input);

     p = new ArrayList<>();

     while(sc.hasNext())
     {
          current_token = sc.next();

          if(current_token.equals("end"))
            {schedule(); break;}

          switch(current_token)
          {
                case "processcount":
                    s.setProcessCount(sc.nextInt());
                    System.out.println(s.getProcessCount()+ " ");
                    break;

                case "runfor":
                    s.setRunTime(sc.nextInt());
                    System.out.println(s.getRuntime +" ");

                case "use":
                    s.setType(sc.next());
                    System.out.println(s.getType() +" ");
                    break;

                case "quantum":
                    s.setQuantum(sc.nextInt());
                    System.out.println(s.getQuantum + " ");
                    break;

                case "process":
                    Processes pl = new Processes();

                    pl.setProcessName(sc.next());
                    System.out.println(pl.GetProcessName()+ " ");

                    pl.setArrivalTime(sc.nextInt());
                    System.out.println(" "+ pl.getArrivalTime());

                    pl.setBurstTime(sc.nextInt());
                    System.out.println(" " + pl.getBurstTime());

                    s.setProcess(pl);
                    // add info
                    p.add(s);

                    break;

                default:
                    // the current_token is not what we are looking for
                    break;
           }
      }
}
```

Comment: This is not working when I put in the input. I am still not getting my results. I am getting "2" as result

Comment: result for what? All the fields?

Comment: I asked for help for my current solution this is not working at all.. all it outputs now is 2, i have no knowledge why

Comment: Indeed my code is not working properly, I just wrote it on the fly to try to show you another way to look at your problem. Beware that every time you use any "next" function of the scanner to get a token, your moving the cursor in your file/source. You might want to debug to see what is actually inside each variable. I could show you my code fixed( < 5 mins with debugger) but that won't really let you practice debugging.

Comment: I already told you why your code is not working and what tool you can use to fix it... You should normally be able to fix it by yourself now....

Answer (score 0):

You're having an issue because of the way you split the string. The way you have right now first replaces each space with a dash. For example, the string

```
"processcount 2   # a comment"
```

would become

```
"processcount-2---#-a-comment"
```

and then splitting that gives you an empty string between every pair of dashes, so you'll end up with

```
token = ["processcount", "2", "","", ... etc]
```

I suggest that you do this:

```
String str = (sc.nextLine().split("#"))[0]; //get the string before the pound sign 
str = str.trim(); //remove the leading/trailing whitespace
token = str.split("\\s+"); //split the string by the whitespaces
```